# How to develop unlock HTC 8X in 2020

Tags: 8.1, htc-8x

I have tried some methods like WP internals or OTC updater (update to Windows 10 mobile) but nothing works at all. Can anyone please help me out or my phone will be permanently a brick phone.

I have read this post but i can't understand it: [Secure Boot flaw for WP](https://gus33000.me/2019/01/05/secureboot-flaw-for-all-wp-devices-literally/)

Comment: Can you please be specific about what OS build the phone is currently running? I believe Microsoft shut down the servers required for dev-unlocking WP7.x and 8.x, but W10M has built-in support for dev-unlock and that still works. Do you mean you tried to update it to W10M but were unable to do so?

Comment: @CBHacking I'm using Windows Device Recovery Tools' OS version - 8.10.14203.306. The tool doesn't recognize phone's firmware and OS version. Also i have encountered random restart / shutdown problem on that OS version (8.10.14203.306). HTC 8X cannot be updated to W10 mobile by OTC updater, i tried it. All Microsoft related things never can be accessed, although sometimes luckily i can open Store but i can not use "Install from SD card" (it have never appeared, i copied XAP file from my PC).If i can't deployed apps to my device, i can't do anything except basic activity and surf the web.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has discontinued the service that was required for dev-unlocking WP devices. Windows 10 Mobile can still be dev-unlocked, because that's built into the OS, but the HTC 8X never got an official W10M build.

Your options, as I see them:

1. Get a newer phone. The 8X is something like 7 years old now, in smartphone terms that's well past obsolete. You can still use Windows Phone apps on a device running W10M, like the HTC One M8, Lumia 950, or so on.
2. Try to find an unofficial ROM for the 8X that either includes W10M or is already dev-unlocked, and flash it using the official flashing tools (WDRT installs command-line tools such as `thor2` that you can use to flash ROMs).
3. Try to use WPInternals to get USB Mass Storage access to the phone's internal storage, at which point you can edit its registry directly to enable dev unlock (and other changes).

All other approaches I can think of for the 8X would require already being dev-unlocked. I never had one myself, and some people who did managed other unlocks for the 8X including "interop unlock" which is a super-dev-unlock that requires editing the registry directly (usually dev-unlock was an intermediate step to get that, though, and back then you could still use the Microsoft developer registration tool). I'm afraid at this point any WP device that can't run W10M is basically worthless, capable only of running a very outdated browser and email client and unable to install almost anything. W10M isn't supported, per se, anymore either, but at least its store still works (last I checked) and its browser is outdated but not nearly so badly.

Thus, if you can't manage to get W10M on your 8X - and bear in mind that while it meets the minimum requirements, it won't be able to run W10M *well* - it's probably time to retire it.